# X86 64 AT&T using exponents for a function?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, exponent

My program is trying to mock a function that uses exponents. The function is

x * y^5

I have x in the register rsi, and y in the register rcx

I am trying to use shlq %rsi, %rcx twice which should be y^4 then just 
using imulq to make it get to the y^5 point, but I don't know how to use 
the function shlq when the value is inside a register. It has to be a $ number value in all the examples online. Not sure what to do. Thanks.

Comment: If you consult any manual you will see that `shl` also accepts a count in `%cl`. That said, I don't think your formula is correct.

Comment: If I move my number from register rcx into cl I can just do shlw %cl, %rsi?

Comment: There is no need to move it anywhere, `cl` is the low 8 bits of `rcx`. Assuming your number fits into 8 bits, it's already there. I still think your formula is broken.

Comment: Do you mean the formula as in the command shlq %cl, %rsi or the idea of using it twice and multq?

Comment: Your formula for calculating x * y^5 is incorrect. It's not the same as `(x << y << y) * y`, using C syntax. It's the same as `x * y * y * y * y * y`, or saving one multiply `tmp = y * y; x * tmp * tmp * y`.

Comment: Ok I understand what to do. Is there a way to check if I got the correct answer? like to print out what the value is inside rax?

Comment: You can use a debugger or use `printf` to print it out.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm missing something especially clever, but I cannot figure out why you are trying to use a left-shift operation to perform exponentiation. You would do a left-shift to achieve a binary multiplication (multiplication by a power of 2). For example, if you wanted to multiply *n* by 2, you would shift *n* left by 1. Shifting *n* left by 5 would be equivalent to *n* × 32.

For exponentiation, you want *n* × *n* × *n* × …. You can't get that with a left-shift operation. You need a good old multiplication.

> x * y<sup>5</sup>

can be rewritten as:

> x * (y * y * y * y * y)

or:

> temp = (y * y)
>   x * temp * temp * y

The third is, in fact, what a C compiler would transform the second formula into, since it is a basic optimization that elides a multiplication.

Assuming that you have `x` in `rsi`, and `y` in `rcx`, in assembly, this would be:

```
movq   %rcx, %rax   ; make a copy of 'y'
imulq  %rcx, %rax   ; y * y
imulq  %rcx, %rsi   ; (y * x
imulq  %rax, %rsi   ; y * x * (y * y)
imulq  %rsi, %rax   ; y * x * (y * y) * (y * y)
ret                 ; result is in RAX
```

Simple enough, and `imulq` is going to be nearly as efficient as `shlq` on modern, 64-bit processors. So this is not slow code, and more importantly, it is *correct*.

---

As for how you shift by a variable count, Jester has already answered that in the comments, but allow me to flesh it out a bit more. There are four basic encodings for the shift instruction on x86 (ignoring operand *size*, and just looking at operand *type*):

1. Shift where the destination is a register and the source is an immediate/constant.
2. Shift where the destination is memory and the source is an immediate/constant.
3. Shift where the destination is a register and the source is the `cl` register.
4. Shift where the destination is memory and the source is the `cl` register.

You can see this by looking at the [documentation for one of the shift instructions](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_285.html). (For historical reasons, there is also a special encoding for shifting by 1. Not important here.) Note that the "source" and "destination" are a bit of a formality here. The "destination" is the value that is *being* shifted, as well as the place where the result is going to end up. The "source" is not actually a source; it is just the shift count.

So, most of what you see is shifting an enregistered value by an immediate, which is option #1, but you can also shift an enregistered value by a variable—the catch is that that variable *must* be in the `cl` register. `cl` is the lowest 8 bits (byte) of the `rcx` register.

So if you wanted to do, say:

> x * 2<sup>y</sup>

which is equivalent to:

> x << y

and `x` was in `rsi` and `y` was in `rcx`, you could write that as:

```
shlq  %cl,  %rsi
movq  %rsi, %rax
ret                 ; result is in RAX
```

Of course, since the shift count must be in `cl`, and `cl` is an 8-bit register, the shift count can never be greater than 255. That is not actually a problem, though, because it is meaningless to shift a 64-bit quantity by any more than 63.